# Gloabal variable lost between function calls

Tags: python

I have code that is like this

```
global _portlist1

def Identify():
 #do something
 _portlist1=["a","b"]

def RunTest():
  print _portlist1
  #do something else

def run():
 Identify()
 RunTest()
```

In RunTest(), _portlist1 is empty, but it was defined in Identify() . Since its a global variable, shouldn't its value have been changed after running Identify()

Comment: also unless you have a reason not to, you may want to put _portlist1 in a class and move your functions to be methods of that class. Then you don't need the global key word.

Comment: Make sure that you understand the `global` statement. " It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals. It would be impossible *to assign to a global variable* without global" from http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need this:

```
def Identify():
    global _portlist1
    _portlist1 = ["a", "b"]
```

I.e. declare the global variable *inside* the function. Otherwise, a local variable will shadow it.

Comment: You also should have pointed out that the "global" statement on the module level is unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

`_portlist1` in `Identify()` is local. Python doesn't care that it has the same name as another variable outside the function. You have to declare it as `global` inside the function as well.

```
_portlist1 = None

def Identify():
    global _portlist1
    _portlist1 = ["a","b"]
```

Although you don't need to assign something to `_portlist1` outside of the function, I like to do so. Otherwise, if you don't call `Identify()`, you'll get a `NameError`. Of course, you can always catch a `NameError`; it's just my style to do LBYL in this circumstance, since it also makes it easier to read IMHO.